# Discrete Fourier Transform of a shift of a tuple over a finite field

Tags: fourier-series, finite-fields

Let $a = a_0 a_1 \cdots a_{N-1}$ be a sequence over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$, where $N \mid q^n-1$ for some $n$. Let $\xi_N$ be a primitive $N$-th root of unity in the extension $\mathbb{F}_{q^n}$. Suppose we know a Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT) of $a$, given by
$$
A_i = \sum_{j=0}^{N-1} a_j \xi_N^{ij}.
$$
Fix $u$ with $0 \leq u \leq N-1$. What is the DFT of the sequence $(a_{j+u \pmod{N}})_{j=0}^{N-1}$? That is, can we write the DFT of the shifted sequence in terms of the DFT of the original? Thank you.

Comment: Presumably $a_{j+u} = a_{j+u \bmod N}$? If so, the answer to your question: can we write... is Yes. If not, the $u$ new elements $a_N, a_{N+1},\cdots, a_{N-1+u}$ need to be defined, and no simple relation exists.

Comment: I'm very sorry for the late reply. I had completely forgotten about this due to some other complications. Yes, $a_{j+u} = a_{j + u \pmod{N}}$ as you guessed. I'll make the edit now. Would you please let me know what is the expression for the shifted DFT in terms of the original one? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Given that we know a Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT) of $a$, given by
$$
A_i = \sum_{j=0}^{N-1} a_j \xi_N^{ij}.
$$
and we fix $u$ with $0 \leq u \leq N-1$,  the DFT of the sequence $(a_{j+u \pmod{N}})_{j=0}^{N-1}$ is
$$
B_i = \sum_{j=0}^{N-1} a_{j+u} \xi_N^{ij}=\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} a_{k} \xi_N^{i(k-u)}=\xi_N^{-iu} \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} a_{k} \xi_N^{ik},
$$
which gives
$$
B_i = \xi_N^{-iu} A_i,\quad 0\leq i\leq N-1.
$$